# Google Analytics - setting the default account

Tags: google-analytics

Every time I log in to Google Analytics, I see the dashboard for a particular account. I want to see a different account and property instead.

How do I tell Google Analytics which account to show me at login?

Comment: For me it always shows me whatever property I last selected. 
If I selected property B to see its stats before I close the browser, then property B is what I'm going to see as default whenever I come back to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I've found is using the favourites tool. Star the views you want to access quickly and they get added to the favourites tab.

[image: GA]

Answer (score 2):

Go to the property and view you you want to see as default and bookmark that page. Now every time you open that bookmark, you will see your desired data.

If you go by the answer by @Some Cat from Japan, you will have to open the analytics account and then select the desired view/property from the favourites which are two steps.

[image: Screenshot of bookmarked analytics account]

Comment: Thanks, Anuvesh. This is the only approach that works for me. Thanks for adding it.